# Compare two arrays each item and return based on condition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Following are the code snippets for the two array containing items.
Here I want first it will iterate the **positionItems**,Take the first item and compare this item with the second array **refundBasedOnPosition**,it it will match then compare the that item label with the distributionAssigningLabel,And here if the lable is equal to the distributionAssigningLabel then it will return the true otherwise false.

In this scenario it will return 'Shashi' because into the first array senior position there so it will take that position and matched with the second array,Second array also contains the position name Senior so after that it will check the label with the distributionAssigningLabel,So it will match and return true.

Could you please take a look and tell me the best optimized way to achieve this? Thanks.

```js
var positionItems = [
      "Director",
      "Vice President",
      "Senior Vice President",
      "Executive Vice President",
      "President","Senior"
    ];
    
 var refundBasedOnPosition = [
      {
        positionName: "Executive Vice President",
        positionCode: "Header",
        label: "Alyson"
      },
      {
        positionName: "Senior Vice President",
        positionCode: "Header",
        label: "Tyson"
      },
      { positionName: "Director", positionCode: "Header", label: "Shashi" },
      {
        positionName: "Vice President",
        positionCode: "Header",
        label: "Shashi"
      },
      { positionName: "President", positionCode: "Header", label: "Shashi" },
      {
        positionName: "Senior",
        positionCode: "Header",
        label: "Shashi N"
      },
      {
        positionName: "Senior",
        positionCode: "Header",
        label: "Shashi"
      },
      {
        positionName: "Vice President",
        positionCode: "Header",
        label: "Shashi B"
      },
    ];
    
    const distributionAssigningLabel = "Shashi";
```

I tried using the following way but it will compare not exactly I want

let isLogginedName = false;

```
let filterRefundBasedOnPosition = refundBasedOnPosition.map((item, index) => {
  if (item.positionName === positionItems[index]) {
    if (distributionAssigningPersonFullName === item.label) {
      isLogginedName = true;
    }
  }
  return item;
});
console.log(isLogginedName);
```

But its not comparing as conditions mentioned .

Comment: Can you show any code that you tried?  And describe where you got stuck.  This place is more about problem solving than it is about being a from-scratch coding service.

Comment: Your requirement is not comprehensible. Pick a smaller, simplified code for people to help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in your code, in the second if condition - "distributionAssigningLabel" the variable name is incorrect and it does return "true" for "Shashi" when you correct it, not because of the senior position, but because of the "President" position which is at Index - 4 during the match condition in your logic.

I am assuming you want to check if the position exists and if it does, then perform a label match with your constant value?